# How to synchronise then() inside for loop

Tags: javascript

I am facing problem while calling a `then()` function inside for loop here is my below code

The chunk of code

```
StretchData.getById(item).then(function (data)
```

Is calling after j==3 but my requirement it should call each iteration Any idea how to achieve this.I tried many things still no result.

```
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

                StretchData.getById(item)
                .then(function (data) {
                    alert(startWorkOutModel.sortValue);
                    startWorkOutModel.inStretchedData = {
                        sort: startWorkOutModel.sortValue,
                        sData: data.result
                    }
                    startWorkOutModel.stretchedData.push(startWorkOutModel.inStretchedData);
                    fl = true;
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(startWorkOutModel.stretchedData));
                    // break;

                },
                function (error) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                });                            

      }
```

Comment: You never appear to be using `j` within the loop. Is that really correct? You want to do the same exact thing three times?

Comment: not enough description. mention problem in description.

Comment: And what's the problem exactly?

Comment: If you need the 'j' value to be 1 for the first then that resolves etc, use a closure to 'save' the value'. But it would be handly to know what exactly the 'j' is supposed to do. And is this native ES6 promises or are you using a library, maybe you can do something with promise.all().progress() .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a loop or array that you need to process asynchronously in parallel, you build up an array of the promises returned by `then` and then wait for them all using `Promise.all`. You'd also normally handle errors on the promise from `Promise.all` rather than individually, unless you're able to do error-correction and return something to use instead of the error.

*Something* along these lines:

```
var promises = [];
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    promises.push(
        StretchData.getById(item)
            .then(function(data) {
                // *** Gets called for each individual item
                alert(startWorkOutModel.sortValue);
                startWorkOutModel.inStretchedData = {
                    sort: startWorkOutModel.sortValue,
                    sData: data.result
                }
                startWorkOutModel.stretchedData.push(startWorkOutModel.inStretchedData);
                fl = true;
                console.log(JSON.stringify(startWorkOutModel.stretchedData));

                // *** Normally you'd want to return something here
            })
    );
}
Promise.all(promises)
    .then(
        function(results) {
            // *** Use results (an array of the promise results) here
        },
        function(error) {
            // *** At least one promise failed
        }
    );
```

As I mentioned in a comment on the question, you're not using `j` within the loop, so that does the same exact thing three times in a row. If you needed to use `j` in the promise callback code, you have two options:

#### ES5 and earlier

Use a function to capture the value of `j` into an unchanging variable the callback can use (since `j` will be `3` by the time any of those callbacks runs):

```
function doRequestFor(value) {
    return StretchData.getById(item)
            .then(function(data) {
                // *** Gets called for each individual item
                // *** Use `value` here (in place of `j`)
                alert(startWorkOutModel.sortValue);
                startWorkOutModel.inStretchedData = {
                    sort: startWorkOutModel.sortValue,
                    sData: data.result
                }
                startWorkOutModel.stretchedData.push(startWorkOutModel.inStretchedData);
                fl = true;
                console.log(JSON.stringify(startWorkOutModel.stretchedData));

                // *** Normally you'd want to return something here
            });
}
var promises = [];
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    promises.push(getRequestFor(j));
}
Promise.all(promises)
    .then(
        function(results) {
            // *** Use results here
        },
        function(error) {
            // *** At least one promise failed
        }
    );
```

#### ES2015 (aka "ES6") and later

You can make use of `let`'s handling in `for` loops which means each loop iteration gets its **own** copy of `j`:

```
let promises = [];
for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
//   ^^^---------------------------- *** Note
    promises.push(
        StretchData.getById(item)
            .then(function(data) {
                // *** Gets called for each individual item
                // *** Use `j` here, it'll be 0, 1, or 2
                alert(startWorkOutModel.sortValue);
                startWorkOutModel.inStretchedData = {
                    sort: startWorkOutModel.sortValue,
                    sData: data.result
                }
                startWorkOutModel.stretchedData.push(startWorkOutModel.inStretchedData);
                fl = true;
                console.log(JSON.stringify(startWorkOutModel.stretchedData));

                // *** Normally you'd want to return something here
            })
    );
}
Promise.all(promises)
    .then(
        function(results) {
            // *** Use results (an array of the promise results) here
        },
        function(error) {
            // *** At least one promise failed
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Variables declared with `var` in JavaScript are function-scoped and not block scoped which means (because the callback is asynchronous) that `j` will be 3 in all callback executions. You can get around that fact by declaring the variable `j` with `let` which instead block scopes it.

```
for (let j = 0; ...
```

Second. Is it important that the callbacks are run in series? In that case you will have to refactor your code considerably. Maybe making the call recursive and chain the next call of the loop to the callback of the first.

If not, but it is still important that you can act when all callbacks are completed, you can store the deferreds in a list and pass them to `Promise.all(yourDeferredList)` which will callback when all are completed.